# Do an Include on list derived on DBQuery

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have an DbQuery and I want to fill another list with my DbQuery Item with some conditions like:

```
var carsList= DbContext.Cars.Where(e=> e.brand == brand);
var myFiltredcarList = new List<Car>();

foreach(var car in carsList)
{
//add items in list according to a condition
myFiltredcarList.Add(car);

}
```

I want to now if is possible to do something like :

```
myFiltredcarList.Include("Brands");
```

I cannot use my myFiltredcarList as List, I want to keep my carsList bidings to do an include in my filtred list(myFiltredcarList)

Is it possible ? 
If it's what I need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible.

First off, the `Include` method is defined on `IQueryable<T>`, and second it works only on **LINQ To Entities** queries, which your list apparently is not.

The only way could be if you can embed the filtering condition into original query like this

```
var myFiltredcarList= DbContext.Cars
    .Include("Brands")
    .Where(e => e.brand == brand && some condition)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: thank for your answer, I can not do all my stuff inside where, i have to work around, but I see what i pretend to do is not possible.